# Rails Status 406 POST response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm been struggling with this issue for the past 4 hours. Whenever I send in a POST request with no arguments (body="{}"), I get a response back with a 406 HTTP Status Error Code.

My controller looks as simple as

```
def resetFixture

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json=>final_obj, :status=>:ok}
    end
  end
```

Routes:

```
match 'TESTAPI/resetFixture' => 'users#resetFixture', :via => :post
```

I'm trying to return a JSON response with "{errCode:1}"

If I do a curl request with -d "" , I get the response I want, but how do I fix this error code? I appeared to have already specified JSON and the status.

It might be more intuitive if I also included the debug logs from the server for the failing request:

Comment: Can you post the exact URL you are posting to?

Comment: I am posting to localhost:3000/TESTAPI/resetFixture

Comment: You need to post to `localhost:3000/TESTAPI/resetFixture.json`

Comment: I have a spec that requires me to post to resetFixture as opposed to resetFixture.json unfortunately.

Comment: I added test logs for the failing request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't request resetFixture.json then you'll need to add the following header to your request:

`Accept: application/json`

This will tell rails that you want JSON back.

You can test this with curl by adding the following argument: `-H "Accept: application/json"`

Alternatively, if you want Rails to always default to JSON you can change your route to:

`match 'TESTAPI/resetFixture' => 'users#resetFixture', :via => :post, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }`